# Resize child UI element in Eclipse RCP

Tags: user-interface, eclipse-rcp

I have a TabFolder which was resized initially. Under the TabFolder is a TabItem and under that TabItem is a Button. The Button inherited the size of the TabFolder so it's huge. What's the best way to resize the Button? Using button.setBounds(...) doesn't work.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(container, SWT.NONE);
    Dimension dim = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();



    TabItem tbtmNewItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmNewItem.setText("1");

    TabItem tbtmBrowse = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmBrowse.setText("3");

    Button btnNewButton = new Button(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CENTER);
    btnNewButton.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
    tbtmBrowse.setControl(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.setText("Push");


    tabFolder.setBounds(0, 0,dim.width-10,dim.height-10);

    createActions();
    initializeToolBar();
    initializeMenu();
    this.setPartName("Home");


}
```

Comment: Your `Dimension dim = java.awt...` line is not of much use with SWT controls.  Use the methods on the `Display` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just removed the button from the control of the tab.

Removed:

```
tbtmBrowse.setControl(btnNewButton);
```

The button can now be resized independently or using setBounds when using a null layout.

Answer (score 0):

So the Control you set on `TabItem` was a `Composite`?  Or a `Button`?

The was to control the size of the button is to create a `Composite` and set that on the `TabItem`.  Then you can add your button(s) to the `Composite`.  You then set a layout on the composite to control how your button(s) are laid out.  See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html for more details on layouts.

EDIT:

To use it, you insert a composite between the tab folder and the button:

```
Composite page = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
page.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
Button btnNewButton = new Button(page, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CENTER);
btnNewButton.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
btnNewButton.setText("Push");
tbtmBrowse.setControl(page);
```

You use layouts to control the sizes of child controls ... in this case, your button.  See the Understanding Layouts article.

Comment: Thanks for the article although with regards to my code, I can't adapt it. I have posted the code snippet.

Comment: You cannot set the bounds of the tabFolder, the workbench will always reset it.